# Ubuntu 12.04 isn't detecting my Alcatel 3G modem

Tags: internet, network-manager, modem, 3g

Today I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and Ubuntu didn't detect 3G usb modem

I tried with `usb_modeswitch` but nothing happened. I have Alcatel one touch X200D and isn't showing Mobile Broadband option in the network manager indicator.

Here is pictures of output of `lsusb` and `usb-devices` command

lsusb:

[image]

usb-devices:
[image]

I hope you will help me.

I only have only Internet so it will be hard to make upgrade because of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

(Data, from your image)

This USB device is brand/model ID **1bbb:0000**, which is **not** a modem.  This simply means the device has **auto-configured** itself as USB flash storage.

Device needs to be reconfigured (using USB_modeswitch) to be **1bbb:0017** (or similar).

Comment: In that case, give the reconfiguration instruction. It may be a comment instead

Answer (score 0):

Sakis3g is best, you can download it from

http://www.sakis3g.org/versions/latest/i386/sakis3g.gz

or the x86_64 version also.

Only compatible for GSM at present.

All you need to do it download and extract the script file sakis3g somewhere.

```
$ cd /path/to/sakis3g
$ sudo chmod +x sakis3g
$ sudo ./sakis3g
```

A GUI follows, where you will be asked for very few details. Also it prompts for username and password. If you don't have username or password, simply enter anything and hit OK.

Hope this works, if not, please let know.